# Start chrome with flags

Tags: google-chrome

I want to start google chrome from linux script and i need to set the event-listeners-default flag to forcealltrue value but i don`t know how to set value on the script. Can you tell me how to set this chrome flag on my script?

Answer (score 0):

[Chromium flags](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags) are added options to the command line used to start an app. You can use them when starting Chromium from the Terminal, in a script, or make a shortcut on the desktop or menu.

Your command would look something like `chromium-browser --event-listeners-default=true` but as per the [list of available flags](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/), there is no *event-listeners-default* so you will need to go back to where you read about that and get the correct phrase to use.